# Inconsistent rounding with printf on octave

Tags: floating-point, rounding, octave

I experience different rounding of numbers in `printf` depending on conditions I don't understand.

```
printf('%1.0f\n',0.5)
printf('%1.1f\n',0.05)
printf('%1.2f\n',0.005)
printf('%1.3f\n',0.0005)
printf('%1.0f\n',1.5)
printf('%1.1f\n',1.05)
printf('%1.2f\n',1.005)
printf('%1.3f\n',1.0005)
```

Gives me the following output:

```
0
0.1
0.01
0.001
2
1.1
1.00
1.000
```

Why is `0.0005` rounded to `0.001`, but `1.0005` to `1.000`?

Comment: What are you using, MATLAB or Octave? The two can have different behaviour. Also, what is the problem here, what don't you understand? Most likely, an attempt is made at rounding, but `1.0005` probably is something like `1.0004999999999` in binary representation.

Comment: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html for playing with representation

Comment: "Why is 0.0005 rounded to 0.001, but 1.0005 to 1.000?" --> Print using `printf('%.20f\n',constant_of_choice)` for greater insight.